# Docker Multi-stage build - Copy failing

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I'm having some issues with a multi-stage Dockerfile for an ejected create-react-app. The Dockerfile is listed below:

```
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

The Dockerfile runs successfully until it gets to step 10 (COPY) where it throws the following error:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2fc8af4cb8db9777246cae48721d8a93917c73e415a02680f1e3a73c8780b903/merged/usr/src/app/build: no such file or directory
```

I've googled away but can't find a clear answer. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: You don't have to `RUN mkdir /usr/src/app` since `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` will do it for you. Also you can simplify `COPY . /usr/src/app` to `COPY . .` since it is your workdir. I don't know what `RUN npm run build` should be doing. Looks like you are waiting for it to create a build directory. To see what it did you can add right after it `RUN ls .` or similar command to see what is there

Comment: Can you test that `RUN npm run build` is actually creating a `build` directory within `/usr/src/app`?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, already verified that npm populates the dir. Problem manifests ramdomly on different machines and environments (even gitlab-ci)

Comment: I also have to same issue. Did you find any solution for this? It's pretty hard to check this because it happens for me randomly and its hard to reproduce.

Comment: Same issue as well. @manixx did you find a solution?

Comment: @Vulpes Actually no, but the error disappeared (or happened less frequently) when I cleaned up Docker and removed unused images and deleted stopped containers.

Comment: can you change the COPY to `/usr/src/app` instead of `usr/src/app/build` to see if this is problem with the build directory?

Comment: I would recommend build an image of builder, and verify that you have a finished build there. You can use `docker build --target builder -t build-test .` to do that. Then you can run it with `docker run --rm -ti build-test bash` and verify you have the the build in /usr/src/app/build with `$ ls /usr/src/app/build`

Answer (score 1):

When you build the application it's building in another cointainer/layer. You i'll need to build the application before and copy the build folder to /usr/src/app.

So, this is fine:

```
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json .
COPY public public
COPY src src

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build

COPY build .

RUN rm -rf src
RUN rm -rf build

FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

I'm removing the src and build folders since that's not necessary and can expose an critical part of your application.

Hence, no doubt about the security of dockerizing an application.

Comment: Why is a react app build, does't not need the ton of files that an application needs to be developed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from that, but my best guess would be that "RUN npm install --silent" is failing, possibly because it can't download one of your packages due to either a network issue or some other reason, therefore your build is then failing and not producing the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using volumes Just because project (and Also dockerfile obviously) was outside Users/[currentuser] folder.. It Easy in "program files". Moving project from program files folder ti Users/[currentuser] It worked. I don't know if it's the same case. Try It and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because COPY . /usr/src/app should be done inside top level directory so that build is created inside /usr/src/app. Do one thing. Put this command 'COPY . /usr/src/app' at the top(before WORKDIR /usr/src/app) and post the output here so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do this would be like the following:

```
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder

WORKDIR /build
ENV PATH /build/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . /build/app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```